# Windows7: Auto start Ad-hoc hotspot if no preferred WiFi network is available

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, hotspot

I am on Windows7 and have two different WiFi routers with two different networks at home. But sometimes both these networks are not available, in that case I want my Windows7 machine to start a hot spot on it's own and start providing the WiFi connectivity.

On Windows7. Control Panel> Network and Internet> Manage Wireless Networks
I created the ad-hoc network connection which will take care of hotspot thing. I put this connection as third in order of connectivity followed by two existing WiFi networks.

The problem is... unlike two other wifi networks, this one is an ad-hoc network, Win7 does not allow it to be connected automatically (due to security reasons) in case two other networks are not available.

This is a headless (without monitor) machine. I have to have some sort of connectivity to control it via VNC or RDP, hence want this hotspot to start automatically when two others WiFi networks are not available.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The article [Connect to Wi-Fi Ad-Hoc Networks Automatically with Windows Vista](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/ad-hoc-networks-routing/) uses
the Windows Scheduler to schedule the connection to the ad-hoc network 1 minute after login.
This will supposedly fail if another network connection is already established.

[Maxidix Wifi Suite](http://www.maxidix.com/) is a commercial product with trial that supports auto connections to ad-hoc networks. At the moment they are running a promotion with 50% discount ($15 instead of $30).

Comment: Thanks Harry. Not a full and concrete answer, but still it is pointing me in right direction. I will try and create a batch file around it and see the result.